# Exibir mensagem(QmessageBox) de outra classe que não a principal em PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

Amigos, peço ajuda de vcs, imagino que seja simples mas estou tendo dificuldade, pois, ainda estou aprendendo orientação a objeto com PyQt4.  Tenho uma classe principal(Aplicacao) separada da classe que forma a tela principal(no arquivo ui_principal.py) do sistema e outra(TrataDiretorio) que tem função específica de verificar se existe o caminho de um diretório e se existir, cria uma pasta dentro dele, mas quero fazer aparecer uma mensagem de erro em uma janela(widget) caso não exista o caminho. Segue o código abaixo:

Classe Principal no arquivo(atualizacao_semanal.py)

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import  (QApplication,QMessageBox)
from PyQt4.QtCore import (SIGNAL, QTimer, QString)
#-------------------------
from ui_principal import *
from tratar_diretorio import *

class Aplicacao(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_JanelaPrincipal):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Aplicacao, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.animacao_titulo()
        self.pushButton_sair.clicked.connect(self.sair)
        self.pushButton_processar.clicked.connect(self.processar_sistema)
    #----------------------------------------
    def sair(self):
        sys.exit()
    #----------------------------------------
    def processar_sistema(self):
        c = TrataDiretorio()
        if c.verificar_criar_diretorio():
            self.pushButton_processar.setEnabled(False)
#------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([sys.argv])
    app.processEvents()
    w = Aplicacao()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Classe TrataDiretorio no arquivo (tratar_diretorio.py)

```
import sys
import os.path
import time
#--------------------
class TrataDiretorio():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data                = None
        self.pasta               = None
        self.diretorio           = None
        self.status              = True
        self.log                 = open('log.txt', 'w+')
    #---------------------------------------
    def verificar_criar_diretorio(self):
        try:
            if os.path.isdir(self.diretorio): # vemos se este dir já existe
                os.mkdir(self.pasta)
                time.sleep(2)
                self.log.write('verificar_criar_diretorio: \n')
                self.log.write('-----------------------------\n')
                self.status = True
                return self.status
            else:
======>         QMessageBox.information(self, u"Informação", u'O caminho <b>"%s"</b> para criação da pasta <b>"%s"</b> não existe!'%(self.diretorio,self.data))
                self.status = False
                return self.status              
        except Exception as erro:
            self.log.write('verificar_criar_diretorio: \n%s\n'%erro)
======>     QMessageBox.critical(self, "Erro", erro)
            self.status = False
            return self.status
```

Comment: Pessoal, vendo alguns questionamentos semelhantes mas com theads no stackoverflow em inglês, vi que bastava criar uma classe e herdar da classe QMessageBox, com isso, bastava utilizar os métodos dessa classe. Então no arquivo tratar_diretorio.py, antes da classe TrataDiretorio, defini a classe Mensagem.

Comment: `class Mensagem(QMessageBox):  
 def __init__(self, parent=None):  
  super(Mensagem, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: No método verificar_criar_diretorio , instanciei a classe e utilizei os seus métodos, importante não esquecer do método ".exec()"

Comment: `msg = Mensagem()`
`texto = u'O caminho <b>"%s"</b> para criação da pasta <b>"%s"</b> não existe!'%(self.diretorio, self.data)`
`msg.setWindowTitle("Informação")`
`msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)`
`msg.setText(texto)`
`msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)`
`msg.exec_()`

Comment: Não estou conseguindo formatar os trechos de código acima.